# Populate in mongoose, how to set the schema name to populate by the field

Tags: nestjs, populate

Ihave a schema of products and schema of orders, im trying to populate product information in orders schema, but just got the string of product id. i Post the product id to orders model as a string of i, maybe i shoud keep it as ObjectId ? if i do, how to do so ?

the product shema:

```
export type ProductDocument = Product & Document;

@Schema({timestamps: true, versionKey: false})
export class Product{
    @Prop()
    title:string;

    @Prop()
    price: number;

    @Prop()
    image: string;

    @Prop()
    description: string;

    @Prop()
    totalAmount: number;

    @Prop()
    counter: string;

    @Prop()
    availableAmount: number;

    @Prop()
    originalPrice: number;
}

export const ProductSchema = (SchemaFactory.createForClass(Product))
```

and the orders schema:

```
export type OrdersDocument = Orders & Document;

@Schema({timestamps: true})
export class Orders {
    @Prop()
    userId: string;

    @Prop({
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: Product.name,
    })
    productId: Product;

    @Prop()
    amount: number;
}

export const OrdersSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Orders);
```

i import model to orders module this way

```
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: Product.name, schema: ProductSchema }])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, i didnt use .populate('productId) in my orders.service